How to get value of Powershell text box and list selection only
I am very new to PowerShell and have two scripts that are interacting with one another. The first script is a GUI that asks users for several inputs, and then stores them as variables. Two types of variables are text and list selections. I am then using the 2nd script to run the 1st, and then send an email.
I am not able to get just the text or selected value of my user inputs. One of the text boxes is below:
I'm just trying to make a lot of repetitive emails we send out easier for my team. Any help is appreciated!
Inputs in the GUI script are as follows:
$ticketNumber = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$ticketNumber.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,30)
$ticketNumber.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($ticketNumber)

$equipment = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$equipment.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,80)
$equipment.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$equipment.Height = 60

[void] $equipment.Items.Add('Laptop, dock, monitor')
[void] $equipment.Items.Add('Laptop, dock, monitor, 2nd monitor')
[void] $equipment.Items.Add('Desktop, monitor')
[void] $equipment.Items.Add('2nd monitor')
$form.Controls.Add($equipment)

Then the 2nd script looks like this:
. "$PSScriptRoot\TestInput.ps1"

$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.Sender = $Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").Accounts.Item(1).SmtpAddress # or 'noreply@domain.com'
$Mail.To = $Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").Accounts.Item(1).SmtpAddress
$Mail.Subject = "Equipment to add"
$Mail.Body = "Ticket: $TestInput.$ticketNumber"
$Mail.Body = "Ticket: $tTestInput.$equipment"

The Email output is this:
Ticket: System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: RITM
Requested: .System.Windows.Forms.ListBox, Items.Count: 4, Items[0]: Laptop, dock, monitor
How do I get just the selected value or the text?

What is $TestInput and $tTestInput ? It seems what you probably want is $Mail.Body = "Ticket: $($ticketNumber.Text) - $($equipment.SelectedItem)"

@SantiagoSquarzon - $TestInput is the 1st script name

TestInput.ps1 is the script name. There is no variable being defined with names $TestInput or $tTestInput in your question.

In your code, $TestInput and $tTestInput are undefined variables and will simply default to $null when interpolated in the string ("..."):
$Mail.Body = "Ticket: $TestInput.$ticketNumber"
$Mail.Body = "Ticket: $tTestInput.$equipment"

The $ticketNumber and $equipment are objects, if you want to interpolate the user input values, for the TextBox you can use .Text and for the ListBox you can use .SelectedItem or .SelectedItems depending on if you're allowing multi-selection. And, if you want to inject these values in the expandable string ("...") you can use the sub-expression operator ($( )), for example:
$Mail.Body = "Ticket: $($ticketNumber.Text) - Selected Item: $($equipment.SelectedItem)"

